# Spring Boot + Websocket + Stomp throws exception when server is idle

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket, amazon-mq

I have spring boot application in which I have implemented websocket + stomp with AmazonMQ. I am able to send messages to queues and consume from client.

Issue is when server is idle for sometime and there aren't any messages sent to queues, I am getting below exceptions. Is it possible to handle this behaviour?

```
2020-05-11 16:10:20.777  WARN 9964 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=24m32s525ms79µs850ns).
2020-05-11 16:10:24.199 DEBUG 9964 --- [clientOutboundChannel-215] o.s.w.s.m.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler    : No session for GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={simpMessageType=OTHER, stompCommand=ERROR, nativeHeaders={message=[Broker not available.]}, simpSessionId=g04vqxdi}]
2020-05-11 16:10:24.513 DEBUG 9964 --- [clientOutboundChannel-214] o.s.w.s.m.StompSubProtocolHandler        : Failed to send WebSocket message to client in session g04vqxdi

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot send a message when session is closed
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.sendMessage(AbstractSockJsSession.java:167) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.tryFlushMessageBuffer(ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.java:171) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.sendMessage(ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.java:144) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.sendToClient(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:473) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.handleMessageToClient(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:460) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:366) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:144) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2020-05-11 16:10:25.086  INFO 9964 --- [tcp-client-loop-nio-1] org.springframework.web.SimpLogging      : TCP connection failure in session _system_: Failed to connect: No such host is known (xxx.xxx.xx-1.amazonaws.com)

java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (xxx.xxx.xx-1.amazonaws.com)
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1248) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:148) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:145) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:145) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:43) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:63) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:55) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:57) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:32) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:108) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:200) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect(Bootstrap.java:162) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:116) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator.lambda$connectChannel$0(PooledConnectionProvider.java:223) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4110) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4216) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4082) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4018) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimplePool.drainLoop(SimplePool.java:201) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimplePool.drain(SimplePool.java:172) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimplePool.doAcquire(SimplePool.java:132) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.request(AbstractPool.java:336) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onSubscribe(PooledConnectionProvider.java:476) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimplePool$QueueBorrowerMono.subscribe(SimplePool.java:324) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider.disposableAcquire(PooledConnectionProvider.java:198) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider.lambda$acquire$3(PooledConnectionProvider.java:159) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen.subscribe(FluxRetryWhen.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryWhen.subscribeOrReturn(MonoRetryWhen.java:50) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:48) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRepeatWhen$RepeatWhenMainSubscriber.resubscribe(FluxRepeatWhen.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRepeatWhen$RepeatWhenOtherSubscriber.onNext(FluxRepeatWhen.java:229) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:693) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:569) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(FluxFlatMap.java:339) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$DeferredSubscription.request(Operators.java:1561) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRepeatWhen$RepeatWhenMainSubscriber.onComplete(FluxRepeatWhen.java:159) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onComplete(SerializedSubscriber.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onComplete(FluxRetryWhen.java:170) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:189) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.FutureMono$FutureSubscription.operationComplete(FutureMono.java:179) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:570) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:549) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:604) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$CloseFuture.setClosed(AbstractChannel.java:1158) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.doClose0(AbstractChannel.java:760) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(AbstractChannel.java:736) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(AbstractChannel.java:607) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.close(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1352) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeClose(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:620) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.close(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:604) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$8.operationComplete(SslHandler.java:2080) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$8.operationComplete(SslHandler.java:2069) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:551) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:183) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.safeClose(SslHandler.java:2069) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.closeOutboundAndChannel(SslHandler.java:1858) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.close(SslHandler.java:724) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeClose(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:620) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.close(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:604) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.close(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:470) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.close(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:957) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:232) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PoolFactory.lambda$static$2(PooledConnectionProvider.java:669) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.AbstractPool.destroyPoolable(AbstractPool.java:151) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimplePool.maybeRecycleAndDrain(SimplePool.java:162) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimplePool$QueuePoolRecyclerInner.onComplete(SimplePool.java:402) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:135) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:45) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4110) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimplePool$QueuePoolRecyclerMono.subscribe(SimplePool.java:454) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4110) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4216) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4082) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4018) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onStateChange(PooledConnectionProvider.java:387) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:414) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onOutboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:384) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onComplete(ChannelOperations.java:201) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.DirectProcessor$DirectInner.onComplete(DirectProcessor.java:349) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.DirectProcessor.onComplete(DirectProcessor.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.tcp.reactor.ReactorNettyTcpConnection.close(ReactorNettyTcpConnection.java:80) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler$StompConnectionHandler.clearConnection(StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler.java:903) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler$StompConnectionHandler.handleTcpConnectionFailure(StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler.java:654) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler$SystemStompConnectionHandler.handleTcpConnectionFailure(StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler.java:985) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler$StompConnectionHandler.lambda$initHeartbeats$4(StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler.java:749) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$InboundIdleStateHandler.channelIdle(ReactorNetty.java:634) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler$ReaderIdleTimeoutTask.run(IdleStateHandler.java:504) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler$AbstractIdleTask.run(IdleStateHandler.java:476) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-all-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2020-05-11 16:10:25.101 DEBUG 9964 --- [tcp-client-loop-nio-1] org.springframework.web.SimpLogging      : Cleaning up connection state for session _system_
2020-05-11 16:10:28.932 DEBUG 9964 --- [MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.s.t.h.DefaultSockJsService       : Closed 1 sessions: [g04vqxdi]
2020-05-11 16:10:29.538  INFO 9964 --- [tcp-client-loop-nio-3] org.springframework.web.SimpLogging      : TCP connection failure in session _system_: Failed to connect: xxx.xxx.xx-1.amazonaws.com
```